# Embed a jquery mobile page into another one (without iFrame)

Tags: jquery, mobile, embed

I have a jquery mobile page, containing a listview. Is it possible to reduce its size and embed it into another page without an iFrame? I tried wrapping it in a div but i have some problems, like during the slide transitions the next page appears at the right and then slides, also if I set div overflow to hidden. Embedding it into an iFrame gaves me incompatibility problems with some mobile browsers (like Android 2.3 stock browser).

Sorry for my bad english and thanks for the help.

Comment: You could try loading the html with ajax and appending it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved wrapping the page into 2 divs, with the outer one limited in size by CSS